# Confirmation box before closing tab, not when page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

My client requirement is to give an alert message when browser tab of my web application is closed. It can be done using JavaScript `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` event.

But there are many drop-down boxes in my application and selecting some of drop-down boxes,  page needs to be reloaded. During this reloading each time `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` is fired and alert message is displayed. I want to stop firing this `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` event on reloading page but display alert message when browser tab is closed. If there were any changes in URL, it would be helpful. But my URL is not changed.

**I know there is no direct JavaScript event support for this situation. Can anyone suggest alternative solution?**

**Update:**

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">  

    var g_isPostBack = false;        
    function windowOnBeforeUnload()
    {        
        if ( g_isPostBack == true )
        return; // Let the page unload

        if ( window.event )
        window.event.returnValue = 'Are you sure?'; // IE
        else
        return 'Are you sure?'; // FX
     }
    window.onbeforeunload = windowOnBeforeUnload;    

</script>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {             
          this.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "OnSubmitScript", "g_isPostBack = true;");

        }
```

Comment: I suggest you using Ajax, this will help you to update/select any dropdown without reloading/refreshing the entire page.

Comment: It's an ERP solution and already developed product. So changing every post-back to Ajax call in each and every pages will not be easy enough. :(

Comment: can you please share the code, so that we'll try to figure it out

Comment: I just need to display alert message only when user clicks on browser's tab Xclsoe button. `window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "you have unsaved changes, if you leave they will be lost";
}`

Answer (score 0):

try the below code and update us if this is your requirement.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var new_var = true;
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (new_var) {
            return "you have unsaved changes, if you leave they will be lost"
        }
    }
    function unhook() {
        new_var = false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code will always display alert message (because it's always true) at the time of both tab closing and reloading.

Comment: you want it only on closing?

Answer (score 0):

faced the same problem try this script

```
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        function confirmExit() {
            return "You are about to exit the system before freezing your declaration! If you leave now and never return to freeze your declaration; then they will not go into effect and you may lose tax deduction, Are you sure you want to leave now?";
        }
        $(function() {
            $("a").click(function() {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            });
            $("input").click(function() {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            });
        });
    </script>
```